# how to implement check on correct days per month in this regex

Tags: regex

I have a regex which works fine for the format except it doesn't work when incorrect days per month is provided like 31 days in Nov or 28 days in Feb

```
^(([012][0-9])|(3[01]))-([0][1-9]|1[012])-\d\d\d\d [012]{0,1}[0-9]:[0-6][0-9]:[0-6][0-9]$
```

Format to support

`DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^(?:(?:(0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])|(29|30)-(0[13-9]|1[0-2])|31-(0[13578]|1[02]))-\d{4}|29-02-(?:\d{2}(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])00))\s(?:[01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d$
```

Let's breakdown the regex pattern:

1. Valid days for months with 31 days: `31-(0[13578]|1[02])`
2. Valid days for months with 30 days: `(29|30)-(0[13-9]|1[0-2])`
3. Valid days for all other months, including February in non-leap years: `(0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])`
4. Valid days for February in leap years: `29-02-(?:\d{2}(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])00)`
5. Time validation: `s(?:[01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d`

Please note that while regex can be used to validate dates to some extent, it's still not the best tool for this task. I recommend using a dedicated date library or built-in language functions to parse and validate dates if possible.